# Allowing remote server access while preventing file transfers

Tags: linux, ssh, security, vnc

I am setting up a Linux server that needs to:
(1) Allow remote access.
(2) Prevent files from being downloaded.

Specifically, the server holds data that users will be analyzing, building models with, etc.  Users will need to access the server from their work computers (also running Linux).  However, they should not be able to transfer data from the server to the users' work computers.

Right now, the only solution I've thought of is setting up two layers of accessing: the user first ssh's or VNC's into an intermediate server and then VNC's from the intermediate server into the main server.

Is there a simpler solution?  (Preferably a solution without remote desktops.)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no simple solution to this. If they can see it, they can copy it. This is a social problem, not a technical one - if you can't trust them to handle the data correctly, they shouldn't have access to it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a perfect solution to this. If you are allowing access to the data there will inherently be a way to get it to the client machine and to get around limitations put in place. I would suggest disabling ssh file transfer right of the bat and look at whitelisting applications allowed for use from the server.